# How to find the jquery exact version for development

Tags: jquery

nowadays I am learning jquery. I often find jquery code from internet  and whenever i wants to use it in my coding I do not know that what is the correct version for this snippet. my question is thas why this happen . and why jquery conflict occurs. Either the every jquery version is developed is different from the previous one or there is another issue. because we all know that it is still jquery in every version.

please solve my problem , necessarily these two points;

1. how to find the exact jquery version
2. and which jquery version should i start to learn

Comment: What do you mean by question #1? Do you mean the version being used on some web site, or the version that a particular application requires?

Comment: questo #1 means that if i writes a jquery snippet then what jquery version should i include in header or footer

Comment: You should use whatever jquery version you know your code works with. 99% of code will work with most recent versions.

Comment: thanks  i am feeling relax now.....

Comment: please review my this problem....thansks in advance    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25442057/jquery-split-function-is-not-working-for-more-than-two-times?noredirect=1#comment39695344_25442057

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking, but it appears that you don't understand some things about development using jQuery so I will attempt to explain those.

First off, there are many different jQuery versions.  New jQuery versions are often not 100% compatible with older jQuery versions.  In the interest of making things better or smaller, jQuery sometimes changes APIs or removes older APIs that have been superceded.  For example, the jQuery 2.x versions have removed support for older versions of IE and thus removed code to make them smaller and faster.   One factor a developer will use to choose between a 1.x or 2.x jQuery version for their project is the desired browser support.

Second off, because of the above issue code originally written to work with a particular version of jQuery may or may not work with a newer jQuery version - it all depends upon which APIs the code uses and whether those APIs or their behavior were modified in any way in the newer version of jQuery.

So, imagine you find a jQuery plug-in on the web that you want to use in your project.  That plug-in will have been developed and tested with certain jQuery versions.  You have to either use one of those jQuery versions that it is known to work with or you will have to do your own testing/debugging/fixing to make it work with your desired jQuery version (if that version isn't already supported).

You should generally avoid using multiple versions of jQuery in the same project because it complicates development and requires larger downloads.

---

If you are picking a version of jQuery to use with your own code and not concerned with other plug-in code compatibility, then you will want to pick the latest stable/tested version in either the 1.x branch or the 2.x branch, depending upon whether you want smaller and faster, but can live without support for older versions of IE (the 2.x branch) or you want more old browser compatibility (the 1.x branch).

---

The compressed or minified versions of jQuery are typically used for a product deployment (the actual live website).  The non-compressed versions are typically used during code development because they allow developers to step into and through the jQuery code to track down problems.

Comment: thanks mr jfriend00 ... i am more than 90% satidfied. further i do my practice.

Comment: one thing more please review my this problem....thansks in advance    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25442057/jquery-split-function-is-not-working-for-more-than-two-times?noredirect=1#comment39695344_25442057

Answer (score 0):

Always use the last version. jQuery is designed to be compatible with old browsers (very old ones if you use the 1.x branch) as well as the new ones (hence the need to use a new version). There's no benefit in not always using a recent one.

Don't just copy-paste code "from internet" : understand how it works as you rewrite it. If a function went missing in a new version, you'll find help in the documentation of the function. That will be rare anyway, unless you felt on very old blogs, as jQuery API is very stable.

Comment: I'm unsure if this question should be closed or not. In any case my answer is CW and can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

open jquery.min.js or jquery.js with any text editor, you'll find the version number on top of the file.

start from 1.11.1 if you want to work with IE8 or lower IE version. Or else just use 2.1.1

Comment: please one more thing ...what do we mean by jquery.min version.
either it is small/cpmpressed version or ......

Comment: It means the code has been "minified", which is compresses the code to make it download faster.

Comment: ok i got that....then it means if i use minified version or normal version . there is no issue

Comment: yes, .min.js means it's a compressed version. you'll find many .min.js/.min.css some days, they works the same as .js/.css without .min.